# Can't run unit tests in .net, shows that "0 tests ran successfully"

Tags: .net, mstest

I'm using a project with .net4.7.2, and when I'm trying to either run or debug a unit test (mstest), it doesn't run anything and it shows:
"Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms"

The output shows:

"No test is available in {path of dll file} Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

No test is available in {path of dll file #2} {path of dll file #3}. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

No test is available in {path of exe file #3} Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again."

It worked before and when I cloned it now from git tests don't work anymore.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a generic method in your test class? Even a private one?
This seems to break the tests.